# Why do Jehovah's Witnesses have a problem with my relationship with one of their members?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

Hi I am new here but there is this question that bothers me. It concerns the marriage between JW and another congregation.  I am currently dating a JW member who is also of that background. Everything is been fine until he comes to say we can't get married because I am not from his church and that the church will disfellowship him and that none of his siblings will attend the wedding if he pushes through.

My question is: **do Jehovah's Witnesses see other Christians as unbelievers?**

I am a Catholic and he is a Witness; why would I be viewed as an unbeliever?

Comment: I'm very sorry for your heartbreak.  There are actually very significant differences in doctrine between Catholicism and the Jehovah's Witnesses, particularly regarding the person of Jesus Christ.  Catholicism (and much of Christianity) affirms the eternal Trinity as an essential doctrine, while the JW's deny it as an essential doctrine.  To the JW, Jesus is a created being.  Unfortunately, these are irreconcilable.  There are many doctrines that are minor issues, the Person of Jesus Christ is not one of those.  I encourage you to research JW doctrine more thoroughly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site does not function as a pastoral site, but a place for information.  As such, this question will be closed.  I encourage you to talk to your priest or other strong Christian friends you may have regarding your situation.

Comment: Thanks narnian  but why should doctrines leave so many things unfulfilled ? Is jehovah witness christianity or another religion.the word christian is from christ( jesus) which means christ followers or disciple (the apostles were first called christians at the church in anthioc) the bible says he is the son if God.

Comment: Does that mean we CANT be married?  Cos of tge doctrine

Comment: @ Tess As Narnian said we do not trust ourselves to give pastoral advice, nor do we ever judge whether or not anyone or any religion is Christian. I'm sorry that you are in the position you are in, but it not for us to judge anyone or anything that judgment is reserved for Christ alone.

Comment: @tess That means that the Jehovah's Witnesses will only accept your marriage if you convert.  I'm really sorry.

Comment: I know a married could where the man is a Catholic and the wife is JW and AFAIK their adult children are neither.  I think this is a good question, it just needs some editing if it gets closed.

Comment: The bible tells us not to be unequally yolked.  You're not going to be able have deep conversations of faith and when the two of you have completely different understands about who Jesus is.

Comment: Sometimes we have to sacrifice something for the sake of love. JW are also Christians in some way. Will you face any problem if you convert to JW? I can't understand why people don't want to change their denomination. I also can't understand why JW can't marry other denominations. Maybe because I don't have denomination(chuckles).

Comment: @Mawia: I think most Christians and JWs would not see JWs as simply "another denomination". JWs have very different beliefs about Christian fundamentals (like who Jesus is!) - it is more like a different religion influenced by the Bible rather than a denomination of Christianity.

Comment: If you married, neither your religion nor his would be happy with the situation, but as far as I'm aware (I'm ex-JW), this is **not** actually a disfellowshipping matter (i.e., he would be allowed to remain a Witness).

Answer (score 4):

As one of Jehovah's Witnesses he really shouldn't even be *dating* anyone outside the congregation either since dating is a precursor to marriage.

tacosalad is correct, that is the reason we do not marry outside our faith. The scripture that really elaborates on this is [2 Corinthians 6:14](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/2-corinthians/6/#v47006014)

> "Do not become unevenly yoked with unbelievers. For what fellowship do righteousness and lawlessness have? Or what sharing does light have with darkness?"

What this means is that our beliefs are not compatible with other religions. A good example from the bible is king Solomon. He married wives that worshiped pagan gods. In time he too started to worship them and was punished for it. By marrying only in the lord we don't have to worry about distractions that may lead us astray.

Our perception and understanding of God and Jesus is different than the Catholic standpoint. We don't believe in the trinity, hell, that most of us will not be going to heaven, so on.

Ask yourself this: What will we teach our children? What are we going to do about holidays? (We don't celebrate the holidays.)

If you were to study with the intent of becoming baptized then it would be OK for you to date. However, you would not be able to get married in a Kingdom Hall until both of you are baptized witnesses.

I am surprised that the elders haven't counselled him about this. Unless that is they don't know.....

You are correct in your last question. 'Do JW see other Christians as unbelievers?', we see other religions as false. [2 Timothy 3:1-5](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/2-timothy/3/#v55003001)

> *"But know this, that in the last days critical times hard to deal with will be here. 2  For men will be lovers of themselves, lovers of money, boastful, haughty, blasphemers, disobedient to parents, unthankful, disloyal, 3  having no natural affection, not open to any agreement, slanderers, without self-control, fierce, without love of goodness, 4  betrayers, headstrong, puffed up with pride, lovers of pleasures rather than lovers of God, 5  **having an appearance of godliness but proving false to its power**; and from these turn away."*

I suggest you both go to your respective spiritual leaders and ask for their advice. The longer you let this play out the more heartache if things go south. I wish you the best in dealing with this situation.

Comment: I don't mean to give my own advice in this. Go to a source you can always trust. The bible and prayer to God.

Comment: "Our perception and understanding of God and Jesus is different than the Catholic standpoint. We don't believe in the trinity, hell, that most of us will not be going to heaven, so on." Are you saying that JWs believe that most JWs will go to heaven, but Catholics believe that most Catholics don't go to heaven?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of Jehovah's Witnesses.

Actually, you would be welcomed with open arms. No one has anything against you.

They are just trying to protect your boyfriend from heartache and from being even more tempted to leave the faith. The Bible tells us, at 1 Corinthians 7:39, to marry only in the Lord. Jehovah's Witnesses believe that they are the only true Christian religion, but they want everyone to join them. That is why they go door to door.

He would still get to remain one of Jehovah's Witnesses.